# How does one compute induced representations for modular representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, nt.number-theory, characteristic-p

The set-up is this: Let $G$ be a finite group, and $H$ a subgroup. We are given an irreducible representation of $H, \rho: H\rightarrow GL_n(K)$ (I will notationally identify $\rho$ with its character). I want to decompose $Ind^G_H(\rho)$ into irreducibles. I am given character tables of both $G$ and $H$.

If $K$ were $\mathbb{C}$, Frobenius reciprocity (https://planetmath.org/FrobeniusReciprocity) will do the trick. However, I am in the modular case; meaning: $char(K)||H|$. I still have all the character tables, except now they are Brauer character tables for the correct characteristic.

Is there a method for decomposing $Ind^G_H(\rho)$ into irreducible (Brauer) characters?

Edit: I wanted to make clear that since in the modular case we don't have Maschke's theorem, the ``decomposition'' into irreducibles would be in the Grothendieck group of Brauer characters of $G$. (representations of $G$ wouldn't nec. be direct sums of irreducible representations)

Comment: I don't quite see what do you mean when you say that if K were C Frobenius reciprocity does the trick. Easy example: if you take G abelian, and H the trivial subgroup, $\rho$ the trivial representation and induce it to the whole group. What you get is a representation which is not irreducible, but how do you compute the irreducible factors? In this case you know them a priori (since G is abelian), and Frobenius reciprocity will only tell you that each of them appears once in the induce representation, but says nothing about who they are

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... I am given all the character tables. Here's what I mean: $Ind^G_H(\rho)=\sum a_i\chi_i$. $(Ind^G_H(\rho),\chi_i)=a_i$, and so if we can compute all the $(Ind^G_H(\rho),\chi_i)'s$ then we're done. Frobenius reciprocity does indeed allow to compute those. I know what all the $\chi_i$'s are because I'm given the character tables of $G$ and $H$. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frobenius reciprocity for Brauer characters is a little more complicated (a lot more complicated if you don't have complete tables).  You need the projective characters to compute the multiplicities.  I don't use anything special about the character being induced, though sometimes you can leverage that information (especially if you don't have complete tables).

In GAP, this is easily done:

```
g:=CharacterTable("ON");
# Let g be the O'Nan simple group
chi:=Sum([1..10],i->Random(Irr(g mod 2)));;
# chi is a random reducible Brauer character
ipr:=Irr(g)*DecompositionMatrix(g mod 2);;
# ipr is the list of projective Brauer characters
vec:=MatScalarProducts(ipr,[InducedClassFunction(chi,g)])[1];
# vec is the multiplicity of each Brauer character in chi
chi = vec * Irr( g mod 2 );
# should be true: we have decomposed it correctly.
```

To get the decomposition matrix, you must not only have the Brauer table but also the ordinary table.  You don't need much from the subgroup *H*, just a character to induce and the element fusion from *H* into *G*.

This is theorem 2.13 on page 25 of Navarro's textbook on Characters and Blocks of Finite Groups.

By **projective**, I mean in the module theory sense, an indecomposable direct summand of the regular representation, usually these are denoted Φ<sub>i</sub> corresponding to a Brauer character φ<sub>i</sub>.  I don't mean representation into projective groups, like PGL.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need Frobenius reciprocity: there's a formula for the character of an induced representation which is valid for both ordinary and Brauer characters (called "the Frobenius formula" on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_representation));  thus, writing the induced character as a sum of irreducibles is just solving a system of linear equations.  It's arguably easier for Brauer characters, since there are fewer equations to solve.